# Line integral of vector field using polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am solving

$$\int_C \vec F(x,y) \cdot \,d\vec r$$

where

$$ \vec F(x,y)= \begin{bmatrix}5y \\10x\end{bmatrix}$$

and $C$ is the quarter-circle arc centered at $(0,2)$ and going from the origin to $(2,2)$.

I am able to get the correct answer using Cartesian coordinates as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\vec r(t) &= \begin{bmatrix}2\cos t \\2-2\sin t\end{bmatrix}, \quad t \in (\pi/2, 0) \\
\vec F(t) &= \begin{bmatrix}10 - 10\sin t \\20 \cos t\end{bmatrix}\\
d\vec r &= \begin{bmatrix}-2\sin t \\-2 \cos t\end{bmatrix}\, dt\\
\int_C \vec F(x,y) \cdot \,d\vec r & = \int_{\pi/2}^0 -20 \sin t + 20 \sin^2 t - 40 \cos^2 t\,dt = 35.71
\end{align}$$

(Notice that the integral is done "backwards" because of how I parameterized the curve.)

I am trying to do the same using polar coordinates and getting stuck. Since the curve as stated is not centered around the origin, I first define

$$\vec G(x, y) = \vec F(x, y+2)$$

Then $$\int_C \vec F(x,y) \cdot \,d\vec r = \int_{C'} \vec G(x,y) \cdot \,d\vec s $$

where $C'$ is the quarter-circle arc centered at the origin and going, in Cartesian coordinates, from $(0,-2)$ to $(2,0)$.

Switching to polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\vec s(t) &= \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ t \end{bmatrix}, \quad t \in (-\pi/2, 0) \\
\vec G_\mathrm{polar}(x,y) &= \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\left(5y+10\right)^2 + \left(10x\right)^2} \\ \arctan\left(\frac{10x}{5y+10}\right)\end{bmatrix}
&\text{convert $(5y, 10x)$ to polar}\\
\vec G_\mathrm{polar}(r,\theta) & = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\left(5r\sin\theta+10\right)^2 + \left(10r\cos\theta\right)^2} \\ \arctan\left(\frac{10 r\cos\theta}{5r\sin\theta+10}\right)\end{bmatrix}
&\text{replace x and y with their polar equivalents}\\
\vec G_\mathrm{polar}(t) & = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\left(10\sin t+10\right)^2 + \left(20 \cos t\right)^2} \\ \arctan\left(\frac{20 \cos t}{10\sin t+10}\right)\end{bmatrix}
&\text{sub in parameterized $r, \theta$}\\
d\vec s &= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\, dt \\
\int_{C'} \vec G(x,y) \cdot \,d\vec s & = \int_{-\pi/2}^0 \arctan\left(\frac{20 \cos t}{10\sin t+10}\right) \,dt = 2.13 \neq 35.71
\end{align}$$

What am I doing wrong? I think I have failed to apply the chain rule somewhere.

Comment: Essentially you don't have the correct "Jacobian". Your assumption that $\vec{s} = (a,b)$ where $a,b$ are polar coordinates is incorrect. $d\vec{r}$ is a Cartesian quantity, you cannot do the line integral in another coordinate system without properly changing the vectors first. Look up the definitions of $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ to see what I mean.

Comment: I know that in a double integral, $dx\,dy$ becomes $r\, dr\, d\theta$, and I know that for line integrals in scalar fields $ds = \sqrt{r^2 d\theta^2 + dr^2}$, but the former doesn't apply because this is a single integral, and the second is a scalar quantity and can't be dotted with $\vec G$.

Comment: But it does tell you that $d\vec{s} = d\vec{r} + rd\vec{\theta}$

Comment: Your conversion to polar for $G$ is also not correct. You have to take the definitions of $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ into account.

Comment: ... it does? And $r$ and $\theta$ are scalars, not vectors, so your definition of $d\vec s$ yields a scalar, which I can't dot with $\vec F$.

Comment: How is what I wrote a scalar? $d\vec{r} \equiv dr \hat{r}$ exactly like how $d\vec{x} = dx \hat{x}$. And yes, that should be obvious from the pythagorean theorem inside the scalar definition.

Comment: Could you write out what $d\vec s$ equals in this example? Here's what I see when I read your equation: $d\vec r$ is 0 because the radius is constant, and $r d\vec \theta = 2 \cdot 1$. Add these together to get 2, a scalar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert $G$ properly we need the definitions of $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$:

$$\begin{cases}\hat{r} = \cos\theta\:\hat{x} + \sin\theta\:\hat{y} \\ \hat{\theta} = -\sin\theta\:\hat{x} + \cos\theta\:\hat{y} \\ \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}\hat{x} = \cos\theta\:\hat{r} - \sin\theta\:\hat{\theta} \\ \hat{y} = \sin\theta\:\hat{r} + \cos\theta\:\hat{\theta} \\ \end{cases}$$

Then we get that

$$\vec{G}(x,y) = (5y+10)\:\hat{x} + 10x\:\hat{y}$$

$$ = (5r\sin\theta+10)\cdot(\cos\theta\:\hat{r} - \sin\theta\:\hat{\theta}) + (10r\cos\theta)\cdot(\sin\theta\:\hat{r} + \cos\theta\:\hat{\theta})$$

$$= (15r\sin\theta\cos\theta+10\cos\theta)\:\hat{r}+(10r\cos^2\theta - 5r\sin^2\theta - 10\sin\theta)\cdot\hat{\theta} \equiv \vec{G}(r,\theta)$$

In this case, we parametrize $r(t) = 2$ and $\theta(t) = t$, giving us that

$$d\vec{s} = d\vec{r} + rd\vec{\theta} = (0\:\hat{r} + 2 \: \hat{\theta})dt \equiv \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2\\ \end{pmatrix}dt$$

giving us a line integral of

$$\int \vec{G}(r,\theta)\cdot d\vec{s} = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^0 40\cos^2t-20\sin^2t-20\sin t\:dt = 5\pi + 20$$

Comment: I understand that you are using the hat notation to refer to basis vectors, but I am confused by your definitions of $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$. I don't see how they relate to $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, \theta = \arctan(y/x)$ or why $\theta$ (no hat) appears but no $r$. How do I plug in an arbitrary point $a \hat x + b \hat y$? In other multivariable calc problems involving polar coordinates, when we need the Jacobian (to reference your comment) it is derived from the equations $x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$.

Comment: @Max There's a general explanation, and a quick one. The quick one is that if I have a point in space, which direction would point in the positive radial direction, and which would point in the positive angular direction? This helps su convert vectors into different coordinate systems. If you draw them out, you will see that $\hat{r}$ is a unit vector that points outward, and $\hat{\theta}$ is a unit vector that points counterclockwise, no matter where you are.

Comment: @Max The general answer is that direction vectors for these unit vectors are given by the partial derivatives. $$\vec{r} = \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\:\hat{x} + \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\:\hat{y} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\:\hat{x} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\:\hat{y}$$ $$= \frac{r\cos\theta}{r}\:\hat{x} + \frac{r\sin\theta}{r}\:\hat{y} = \cos\theta\:\hat{x}+ \sin\theta\:\hat{y}$$ This relationship between partial derivatives and direction vectors is a deep connection, and that is how they relate to the formulas you mention.

Comment: @Max You will see that following the same formula for $\theta$ will not give you the formula for $\hat{\theta}$, but that is because the partial derivatives will only give you the direction vector. If you want to make it a unit vector, simply divide by its magnitude.

Comment: OK, I see that now. My next question would be in your second to last line, where you write $d\vec s = d\vec r + rd\,\vec\theta$. Since $s(t) =  r(t) \hat r + \theta(t) \hat \theta$, when you write $\vec r$, you are really referring to the $\hat r$ component of $s(t)$, i.e. $r(t) \hat r$, and hence $d\vec r = r'(t) \hat r dt = 0 \hat r$. Is that right?

Comment: @Max That formula you have for $s(t)$ is not correct. It is unwise to try to come up with a formula for $s(t)$ - do not try to carry over your intuition and notation from Cartesian coordinates because Cartesian is a special coordinate system with special properties. Simply remember that $d\vec{s} = d\vec{r} + r d\vec{\theta}$